# Setting AutomationProperties on templated control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, ui-automation, white-framework

I'm needing be able to set an AutomationId on some controls that are generated from a template based on assets that are checked into a system.

I've verified that all of the custom controls that encapsulate the templated controls handle AutomationId properties.

I've tried the following with no luck:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="assets:IAssetVM">
    <Border Background="Transparent" x:Name="ItemContent" MouseLeftButtonUp="ItemContent_OnMouseLeftButtonUp">
        <Border.InputBindings>
            <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftDoubleClick" Command="{Binding FollowAssetButtonCommand}" />
        </Border.InputBindings>
        <Grid Height="30">
            <AutomationProperties.AutomationId>
                <MultiBinding StringFormat="AID_{0}-{1}">
                    <Binding Path="Name" />
                    <Binding Path="NumericID" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </AutomationProperties.AutomationId>
            ...
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

**Update**

Looking back through the logical tree of the application while it's running I realized that the last level I was able to get to with the automation properties assignment contains a couple of different GroupItem classes (different command modes for the assets in the system).

So the structure looks like:

```
-> List View "" "Test_AssetListView"
    |-> Group Item "Mode 1" ""
         |-> List Item "Vm.Assets.AssetVM2" ""
    |-> Group Item "Mode 2" ""
```

I don't think I should need to override the OnCreateAutomationPeer() method for the Group control as (I'm pretty sure) it's a base(?) type of control.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance for any help!